# How to repeat each element of iterator n times?

Tags: rust

I am currently learning Rust, and I stumbled upon an operation for which I can find neither a standard implementation in std nor a reasonably formed snippet of code, which would do what I would like it to do.

Basically I would like to repeat each element of an iterator a given number of times. So for example if a had an iterator of `[1,2,3]`, then by repeating each element 3 times for example I mean that output should be `[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3]`.

How would one do it idiomatically in Rust?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `repeat(n).take(n)` to repeat the individual elements and [`flat_map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.flat_map) to combine those repetitions into a flat iterator:

```
let it = vec![1, 2, 3].into_iter();
let repeated = it.flat_map(|n| std::iter::repeat(n).take(3));
assert!(repeated.collect::<Vec<_>>() == vec![1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]);
```

A generic version that converts any iterator into a repeated iterator might look like this ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d7b8db7b853fd0484573085d2e239d48)):

```
fn repeat_element<T: Clone>(it: impl Iterator<Item = T>, cnt: usize) -> impl Iterator<Item = T> {
    it.flat_map(move |n| std::iter::repeat(n).take(cnt))
}
```

Comment: Kudos! That was fast.